# Is there a way to connect VSCode to an SQL Anywhere database?

Tags: visual-studio-code, odbc, sqlanywhere

I have seen extensions that allow you to connect to a MySQL database, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc ... But I have not found a way to connect to an SQL Anywhere database (or to connect to an ODBC created in the system).
Does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT: This is the conection data on ODBC (that works):
[ODBC Conecction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQiZ2.png)

Comment: I am using SQL Server(mssql) extension and it works fine to connect to SQL DBS. did you try that?

Comment: @J.K Yes, I tried. Yes, I tried. But It didn't work (Or at least I don't know how to do it). I have also tried with "SQL Tools" and with "vscode-database".

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?    Does SQL Anywhere depend on a freetds or dblib connection?  Is anything like that available in vs-code?  Or will the MSSQL connectors work fine with Sybase Anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I found the extension [database-client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-mysql-client2).  It supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SqlServer, and works fine for me.

Comment: From that link: "This project is no longer maintain for free" :(

Answer (score 0):

1- Check that you have the extension : SQL Server (mssql)

2- Press F1 to show all commands

3- Write "sql" to search, and then choose : "MS SQL : Connect"

4- Fill the needed information step by step, choose SQL as language, server name, username, password, ...

5- Ready to write your first query!!

[image]

Comment: Im doing this and I obtain this error: 

mssql: Error 53: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server). 

Im going to edit the original post with info about conection.

Comment: @AdrianMadu, are you able to connect to the SQL Database using Microsoft SQL server management studio? Because if you can connect, then it should work from Visual studio code using the correct server name, username, and password.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the extension [vscode-database](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bajdzis.vscode-database). I have tried this, and it works flawlessly.